# Logic Gates in Circuit

Tags: java, arraylist, enums

So, in `XOR Gate` of a logical circuit:

- if `all` of input signals are `0` or `1` then the output is `0`;
- if the inputs's signals are mix such as `1110001111` then output is `1`;

but

- if we have signals `0` and `X`(unknown signal), then the output is `X`;
- when `1` and `X` then the output should be `X`.

I have a bug in the code of method because when, let's say `1111100001` signals are fed in the gate, I'm getting `0` instead of `1`. How should I handle if the inputs are `0000000` or `11111`? Note: `Signal.HI` is `1`, `Signal.LO` is `0`, `Signal.X` is `X`.

Please let me know if any more information is needed.

```
@Override
public boolean propagate() 
{
    Signal inputSignal;
    Signal tempSignal;
    Signal temp = getOutput().getSignal();
    List<Wire> inputs = getInputs();
    Signal result = Signal.LO;
    tempSignal = inputs.get(1).getSignal();

    for(int i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++)
    {

        inputSignal = inputs.get(i).getSignal();
        //tempSignal = inputs.get(0).getSignal();

        if(inputSignal != tempSignal)
            getOutput().setSignal(Signal.HI);

        else if(inputSignal == tempSignal)
            getOutput().setSignal(result);


        /*else if((inputSignal == Signal.LO) && (tempSignal == Signal.LO))
            getOutput().setSignal(result);*/

        else if(inputSignal == Signal.X)
        {
            result = inputSignal;
            getOutput().setSignal(result);
            break;
        }
        else            
            getOutput().setSignal(Signal.HI);
.............................................
```

Comment: You should be checking for `if(inputSignal == Signal.X)` before you do `if(inputSignal != tempSignal)`

Comment: Is `Signal` an enum? Why are you comparing specifically to the second input wire (inputs.get(1).getSignal())? Also, your definition of XOR seems a bit off. If it's X and 0, then X. If it's X and 1, *not* X.

Comment: You have to reorder your `if` statements. If the previous value is not `X` and the next values is `X` then your first condition `inputSignal != tempSignal` is `true` and the others are never checked. You have to check for `X` *first* and for `!=` afterwards (and you don’t need another check as when `inputSignal != tempSignal` evaluates to `false` it’s clear that `inputSignal == tempSignal`…   Oh and your definition lacks a specification for the `X` and `X` case…

Comment: Yes, Signal is enum. My specs say that if 1X = X and 0X = X

Answer (score 0):

I would use 3 boolean variables:

- hasX: true if an X has been met
- hasLO: true if a LO has been met
- hasHI: true if a HI has been met

Then loop over the inputs, and set one of the variable based on the value of the current element. If, after the value has been updated, hasX is true, you can break out of the loop: the result is X. If not, you continue.

After the loop, you return 1 if hasLO and hasHI are both true. Otherwise, you return 0.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Could you please show only one of them? @JBNizet

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit simpler this way:

```
public Signal propagate() {
      Signal inputSignal;
      Signal tempSignal;
      Signal temp = getOutput().getSignal();
      List<Wire> inputs = getInputs();
      Signal result = Signal.LO;
      tempSignal = inputs.get(1).getSignal();

      //count number of HI, LO and X-Inputs
      int hi = 0;
      int lo = 0;
      int x = 0;
      for(Signal s : inputs)
          switch(s){
               case Signal.HI:
                    hi += 1;
                    break;
               case Signal.LO:
                    lo += 1;
                    break
          }

     x = inputs.size() - (hi + lo);

     if(x == 0)
          if((hi % 2) == 1)//XOR is HI for an uneven number of HI inputs
               return Signal.HI;
          else
               return Signal.LO;
      else
          return Signal.X;//atleast one x -> unknown result
}
```

Though i don't completely get your definition of XOR. But it might help.